# $f(x,y) = \sin(2x - y) $find the directional derivative from P in the direction from $P(-\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{6})$ to $Q(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Here is what I have so far :

\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{PQ} &= \left\langle0-\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}\right), 0-\frac{\pi}{6}\right\rangle \\&= \left\langle\frac{\pi}{3}, -\frac{\pi}{6}\right\rangle
\end{align}
\begin{align}u &= \frac{1}{\Bigl\Vert\overrightarrow{PQ}\Bigr\Vert} \cdot \overrightarrow{PQ} \\&= \frac{1}{ \sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{9} +  \frac{\pi^2}{36}} } \cdot \overrightarrow{PQ}  \\&= \left\langle\frac{\frac{\pi}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{5\pi}{36}}},\frac{\frac{\pi}{6}}{\sqrt{\frac{5\pi}{36}}}\right\rangle
\end{align}
\begin{align}\nabla F(x,y) &= 2\cos(2x-y)\cdot u_1 - \cos(2x-y)\cdot u_2  \\
\nabla F(x,y) &= 2\cos(2x-y)\cdot\frac{\frac{\pi}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{5\pi}{36}}} - \cos(2x-y)\cdot\frac{\frac{\pi}{6}}{\sqrt{\frac{5\pi}{36}}}
\end{align}

Comment: The answers might be further simplified.

Comment: @Bernard. Why is `\Vert\overrightarrow{PQ}\Vert` prefered over `\left\Vert\overrightarrow{PQ}\right\Vert`?

Comment: With `\left ...\right` the double vertical rules are much too large (probably due to the arrow above). Actually, I used `\Bigl ... \Bigr` instead, for a finer-tuning of the delimiters size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction from $\;P\;$ to $\;Q\;$ is simply $\;Q-P=\left(\frac\pi3,\,-\frac\pi6\right)\;$ , and a unit vector in this direction is $\;\vec u=\frac1{\sqrt5}(2,-1)\;$ (Check this! Simplification included), so as the function $\;f\;$ is differentiable everywhere, we get (and *your work is correct* but haunting: simplify!)

$$D_{\vec u}f(P)=\left(2\cos(2x-y),\,-\cos(2x-y)\right)_P\cdot\vec u=\left(2\cos\frac{5\pi}6,\,-\cos\frac{5\pi}6\right)\cdot\frac1{\sqrt5}(2,-1)=$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(2\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right),\,\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\cdot(2,-1)=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(-2\sqrt3-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)=-\frac{5\sqrt3}{2\sqrt5}=-\frac{\sqrt{15}}2$$

Check the above: there may mistakes (in signs, arithmetic, etc.)